# Term or phrase that means the reverse of "is located at/within"

Tags: antonyms, localization

Consider a thing that is located within another thing, say a particular store (not one of a chain of stores, but a distinct non-fungible individual store) within a particular mall.

We can describe the relationship of the store to the mall as

> The store (ID XYZ) is located at/within the ABC mall

How would the reverse relationship be succinctly described using a single phrase?

> The ABC mall contains store (ID XYZ)

Doesn't convey the right meaning IMHO, and I have never heard *contains* used this way.

> The ABC mall has within it store (ID XYZ)

Is better IMHO.

Is there a clearer/simpler way to say this?

---

Note: I would like a single phrase, not a split one, so **not**

> The ABC mall has store (ID XYZ) located within it

I'm looking for something to fill this gap:

> The ABC mall ... store (ID XYZ)

---

The actual use case is for cataloging the location of all basketball courts used for a competition where multiple sports centres are involved. I want to express almost mathematically that such as such a sports complex *has within it* these particular (named) courts.

This is not about describing what types of courts exist within a sports centre or what kind of services it offers. It’s about the specific location of each specific court.

Comment: A *competition* rather than a *completion*?

Comment: I really don't understand your objection to 'contains'. If one or more particular, identifiable, basketball courts are within a named sports centre in what sense are the courts not _contained_ within the sports centre? I also don't really see why, when you are concentrating on the courts, you need to look at the sports centres first. I, personally, can't see what's wrong with "Courts 17 and 24 are within the Bill Jones Sports Centre" or "The Bill Jones Sports Centre contains courts 17 and 24".

Answer (score 6):

In Britain, in speech rather than writing, I have often heard the construction such as “Bluewater **has** a Boots” (or sometimes colloquially **have**).  In this case Bluewater is a big UK mall and Boots is a chain of chemists.

It is hard to find authoritative written examples, but here are two that indicate the usage of **has**:

In the first, the writer is comparing two malls (Bluewater and Lakeside) for the shops they contain.

[LRUK](https://www.lrukforums.com/threads/i-dont-believe-it.4876/)[image]

In the second, Meadowhall is a UK mall. The dining quarter is a part of the mall that **has** the various chains listed. By implication, the mall itself **has** these restaurants.

> [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meadowhall_(shopping_centre))
>
> The Oasis Dining Quarter is Meadowhall's food court which has food outlets and seating on both floors. The ground floor contains mostly fast food outlets including McDonald's, KFC, Subway, Pizza Hut, Five Guys and Barburrito but includes restaurants Nando's, Harvester and a Wetherspoons.

These examples imply that any shop name could be used as the object of **has**.  The shopping centre or mall, *Derbion* in Derby, UK, for example has *Phase Eight*, a non-chain shop.

Colloquially, people in the UK might say "Derbion has a Boots" when they wish to say that there is a branch of the Boots chemist chain in the shopping centre. The indefinite article points to its being one of many branches.

Comment: 'Includes', also mentioned, is less informal.

Comment: As I tried to say in the question, it’s not about having one store of a chain store, it’s about a specific individual store, like “MyChain Store with serial number XYZ is located within the ABC mall”. It’s about identity. Like “prisoner 12345 is located in cell block B”, it’s not enough to say “cell block B has prisoners”. The meaning must suit identifying a *particular* prisoner, like “cell block B houses prisoner 12345”, where the verb works for non-people. Eg “The ABC sports complex *contains within it* basketball court serial number XYZ” - a hard data point rather than general information

Comment: @Bohemian I understood that but felt that the examples implied that any shop name could be used. *Derbion* in Derby, UK, for example has *Phase Eight*, a non-chain shop.

Answer (score 5):

[Houses](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/house):

> The sports hall **houses** a basketball court, as well as a number of other facilities

> "The gym we're heading to houses the very machines that will be used in the up-coming championships."

This is very similar to `accomodates`, though I think works a little better, and is less ambigious (since accomodates can also mean 'allow in').

I would also say **houses** implies the subject is physically within the sports hall, which **has** does less, even if it is the more colloquial word.

Comment: “Houses” might work, but you’ve missed the point. It’s not about conveying that there is a basketball court, but rather that a *particular individual* basketball court. ie “basketball court serial number ABC123 is located at the sports complex” (and not basketball court DEF456). I want to say that if all the basketball courts in the world, this sports complex has within it these *particular* non-fungible basketball courts.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. If anything, I think that reinforces the case for "houses", rather than "has", since it gives a certain autonomy to the subject involved, highlighting its individual NFT (Non-Fungible Topology).

Comment: Of all the suggestions, I think "houses" best conveys *containing the locality of* and *provides the space for*, even a hint of ownership/management, which to me are all pluses.

Answer (score 3):

In your comment to my former answer you added information which directs to a different answer. Sport centres ***offer*** or ***provide facilities*** such as basketball courts, tennis courts etc. Here is an example:

> The sport centre **provides** *a multi-use sports hall*, *a 60 station fitness suite*, *aerobics area* and changing facilities. ([source](https://royalholloway.ac.uk/about-us/more/local-community/royal-holloway-sport/sports-facilities/))

But there are instances such as:

> The Centre... ***is home to*** an *outdoor tennis court* as well as *play parks* and an *outdoor paddling pool* that is free for public use during the summer months. ([Source](https://www.woodley.gov.uk/parks-facilities/woodford-park-leisure-centre))

However, if you really need to get technical about it, you could use the verb ***comprise***:

> If you say that something ***comprises*** or ***is comprised of*** a number of things or people, you mean *it has them as its parts or members.*
>
> - The lower level *comprises* three double-size bedrooms, a bathroom, and laundry. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/comprise))
> - The field *comprised* a mosaic of conventionally-tilled and rye-mulched plots, surrounded by fields of maize, soybeans, alfalfa hay and mixed hardwood forest. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/comprise))
> - The factory was to be a vast installation, *comprising* fifty buildings. — Jane Jacobs ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comprise))

Comment: I don't think that "comprise" (= consists of) works: *The ABC mall **comprises** the XYZ store*  is patently wrong. The ideas of comprise = "to have within its boundaries" is obsolete or archaic.

Comment: Because it's singular, but "The ABC mall comprises thirty-seven stores, including XYZ," seems reasonable. Unless you're saying that "comprise" in the sense, "is made up of" is obsolete. But I have heard it used that way at the highest levels of government and show business.

Comment: Offers or provides don't work because they lack the concept of identity. It’s not about a general idea of having basketball courts. It’s about stating that of all the basketball courts in the world, basketball court serial number XYZ is located within sports complex ABC. How do we best say “sports complex ABC has within it basketball court XYZ”? Comprises sounds somehow to general. Is home to is not bad though.

Comment: @zan “comprises such and such, including” sounds like brochure content. I’m looking for something clinical, not conversational

Comment: @Bohemian Well, you didn't say the word wasn't being used for a brochure, and if you want something that rings clinical, provide a clinical context. When you include mall and store in your hypothetical construction, it sounds as if you're writing a promotional brochure. You can't lead a horse to sand and expect it to drink water.

Comment: @Bohemian I wouldn't describe "comprise" as conversational. If you check the link form Cambridge I gave, the first thing it says about it is that it is _formal_. But maybe [**_enclose/inclose_**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/inclosed) is closer to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

***[Accommodate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accommodate)***:

> The ABC mall ***accommodates*** the XYZ store.

as in

> The Building also ***accommodates*** a Superdrug Pharmacy and has a further Vacant Unit looking for an occupier.([source](https://keyworkerhomesltd.co.uk/sainsburys-local-store-newton-abbot-devon/))

or

> The pharmacy counter inside Sainsbury's St Annes supermarket has closed as preparations are made for it to ***accommodate*** an Argos store. ([source](https://www.blackpoolgazette.co.uk/business/pharmacy-counter-closes-as-st-annes-supermarket-prepares-for-argos-3272312))

Comment: This is quite good, but is a little stuffy. Actually, I want to describe the relationship between a sports centre and a particular basketball court within in it (such a relationship would exist for all such courts).

Comment: You should include that in your OP.

Comment: @Bohemian emphasising what fev said! It is really annoying that you did not give this information at the start: "*The sports centre **has** a basketball court.*"

Comment: @grey no I do **not** want to say *The sports centre has a basketball court*. I want to say “The sports centre has a *particular individual* basketball court”. Concrete example: “The All England Lawn Tennis and Croquet Club *has within it* Centre Court”. It’s about referring to the specific individuals of both the containing entity and the contained entity. It’s not about availability of a feature or service of a venue.

Comment: MW: **encompass** 1 : **to include (something) as a part** *My interests encompass [=cover, include] a broad range of topics. -- The district encompasses most of the downtown area.*

Answer (score -1):

> is home to

This is also used for major league teams, eg

> Seattle, home to the Seahawks

Although usually used when the “container” is a city, still makes  sense for smaller containers:

> Pikes market is home to the original Starbucks store

Note: A *particular* Starbucks store